# What is a clean way of mocking multiple methods on a class in python?

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, mocking

When writing tests I am often faced with the needed to mock several class methods. Currently I am doing this by nesting `with` statements contain the `mock` references e.g.

```
from ... import A


def test_sample(self)
    instance = A()
    with mock(A, 'function_1', return_value=1):
        with mock(A, 'function_2', return_value=2):
            with mock(A, 'function_3', return_value=3):
                assert A.function_4, 10
```

Is there a neater / recommended way of doing this? It would be nice to be able to remove several nested calls!

During this process there may or may not be other methods on the class that are not mocked.

Comment: Are there other methods in `A` that will run in the test, that are not being mocked?

Comment: Thanks @solarissmoke I have updated the question to add that there may or may not be non-mocked methods

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need to have nested context managers - you can patch all the methods in one go:

```
def test_sample(self)
    instance = A()
    with (mock(A, 'function_1', return_value=1),
          mock(A, 'function_2', return_value=2),
          mock(A, 'function_3', return_value=3)):

         assert A.function_4, 10
```

Alternatively you can use [`patch.multiple`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#patch-multiple):

```
from unittest import patch

def test_sample(self)
    instance = A()
    with patch.multiple(A, function_1=2, function_2=2, function_3=3) as patched_values:
        assert A.function_4, 10
```

Comment: The first option requires python 3.9 or higher

Comment: Thanks @MuhsinFatih -- I had just spent a while trying to get this to work because I didn't see your comment at first! Now trying to find the best way to do this in 3.8

Comment: @RinoBino the second option works with 3.8